# How to apologize

Tags: sentence-construction, expressions

> "I apologize for **not have spoken** to you in person yet."
>
> "I apologize for **not speaking** to you in person yet."

Basically, I’m trying to say:

> "I’m sorry I haven't had the time to speak to you in person yet."

Comment: Your third sentence is just fine.

Comment: “Have” is present tense, while “spoken” is past tense. The tenses should agree.

Answer (score 1):

You can say it like this:

> I apologize for not having spoken to you in person yet.

or

> I apologize for having not spoken to you in person yet.

or

> I apologize for not having had the time to speak to you in person yet.

The first two sentences sound better to me.

Comment: The second example might be grammatical, but it sounds awkward to me as colloquial American English.